# The different ways to specify a generic type

Tags: f#

According to the section here on generic types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233230.aspx then these forms are equivalent:

```
type 'a MyType = ....

type MyType<'a> = ...
```

but the 2nd form allows you to specify a list of type parameters, eg:

```
type MyType<'a,'b> = ...
```

Is this right?

Comment: You can specify multiple types using the first form: `type ('a, 'b) blarg = Blarg of 'a * 'b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right.  There is a way to supply multiple parameters in the first style too:

```
('a,'b) MyType
```

but this is for compatibility and is not recommended.